# Use Struts if Statement inside iterator

Tags: tags, struts2, jsp-tags

I really need your help. I have the following Struts2 iterator?

```
<s:iterator value="familiari" status="entry"> 
</s:iterator>
```

How can I test the addess propery is empty??

the following does not work

```
<s:if test="#entry.addess!=''">
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are misundestanding the meaning of the `status` propery of the [iterator tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/iterator.html): that's an special iterator object to track row number (odd/even checks, etc).

You should use the `var` property. For example (not tested) :

```
<s:iterator  value="familiari" var="myobj"> 
   <s:if test="#myobj.addess != ''">
   </s:if>
<s:iterator>
```

Comment: Since the current iterated item is at the top of the value stack, so there is no need for the var attribute of iterator. The test for the _if_ tag could simply be written as: test="address != ''" It might be interesting to the OP that you could also write: test="address.isEmpty() == false"

Comment: @Quaternion: you are right, it seemed to me more easy to understand with the explicit variable